# How to pass a double pointer from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I have a C++ cli program that pass a double *value to a C# wrapper.

Here is my C++ program

```
MY_DLL_API void __cdecl PassValue(double *value,) {
CSharpWrapper^ CSharpWrapperAPI = gcnew CSharpWrapper();
CSharpWrapperAPI ->PassValue(*value);

return;
```

}

and my C# program

```
 public unsafe void PassValue(double *newValue)
    { // some calcuation }
```

and I get compiler error: cannot convert parameter 2 from 'double' to 'double *' 
How come? the two interfaces are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are dereferencing a `double*`, thus yielding a double.

This:

```
CSharpWrapperAPI ->PassValue(*value);
```

Should be this:

```
CSharpWrapperAPI ->PassValue(value);
```